# Font U/pigpen/m/n/10=pigpen at 10.0pt not loadable: Bad metric (TFM) file

Tags: fonts

On Ubuntu 16.04 with `texlive-fonts-extra` installed, calling `pdflatex` on

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pigpen}
\begin{document}
{\pigpenfont FOO}
\end{document}
```

gives the error `Font U/pigpen/m/n/10=pigpen at 10.0pt not loadable: Bad metric (TFM) file`

Comment: I beg to differ... On my computer (Ubuntu 16.04 too) it works correctly. Try reinstalling `texlive-fonts-extra`...

Comment: Already tried to do that, of course.

Comment: I couldn't possibly know that, of course `:)`

Comment: Sorry, that did come across poorly. Thanks for trying to help!

Comment: No worries `:)`